# How to replace list element with string without double quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a simple list like this:

```
list = ['A','B','C']
```

and to replace element #1 of l1 with this string:

```
str = "'W','T'"
```

I'm doing like this:

```
>>> list[1] = str
>>> list
['A', "'W','T'", 'C']
```

How can I do to replace `list[1]` values    with `str` content without the double quotes? like this:

```
['A','W','T','C']
```

Comment: What is your expected ouput?

Comment: Hi, expected output would be `['A','W','T','C']`. Added the expected output in original post either.

Comment: @GerCas and what would the expected output be for `"'W,X','T'"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert it directly like that. You need to clean it first and convert it to a list and use slicing.

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
str1 = "'W','T'"

new_list = [a.strip("'") for a in str1.split(",")]
list1 = list1[:1] + new_list + list1[2:]
print(list1)  # ['A', 'W', 'T', 'C']
```

I also modified your variable names because `list` and `str` are reserved keywords.

Comment: Note that in-place assignment as in the question is possible, as ``list1[1:2] = new_list``. Also be aware that ``list`` and ``str`` are not keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the elements of the string into a list and then add the list elements to the desired position in your destination list.

```
list_ = ['A', 'B', 'C']
string = "'W','T'"
formatted = [letter for letter in string if letter.isalpha()]
i = 1 #index of element to replace
list_[i:(i + len(formatted))-1] = formatted
print(list_)
```

Answer (score -2):

list[item] = str(list[item])

```py
>>> mylist = [1,3,5]
>>> mylist[0] = str(mylist[0])
>>> mylist
['1', 3, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what I want is to remove the double quotes when reassing the `list[1]` value with `str` content as shown in expected output in original post.

Comment: sry i didn't understand the question... i wasn't sure do you want to strip or just make it string....

Comment: Hi, no problem. Thanks for your help anyway